# printing the current value of matched element in list

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

i built custom xsl to loop on xml list and check if the given id is matched of one of ids in that xml then it will print its own attribute

please help me to achieve it.

XML

```
<companies>
   <company name = "Sila">
      <ID>1</ID>
   </company>

   <company name = "AS&T">
      <ID>2</ID>
   </company>
</companies>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="ID" select="2"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="/companies/company">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="ID = $ID">
                    <Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="companies/company/@Name"/>
                    </Name>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

unfortunately I got all companies names printed which is incorrect in the above example AS&T should be printed only

any idea ?

Comment: *"unfortunately I got all companies names printed"* Not with the code you posted here. All you will get is an error on the XML and an empty `Name` element on the XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="companies/company/@Name"/>
```

For you second question about otherwise

use as below:

```
 <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="ID = $ID">
                    <Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </Name>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!-- Add Your Process -->
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: and how can I apply otherwise part ?

Comment: when I added otherwise part it prints all tags (when tag and otherwise tag ) together for all cases

Comment: what is your requirement in otherwise part?